# How to sort an array that contains strings with letters and numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, alphanumeric

I'm working on a web application that make you a test for choosing your professional vocation, it makes 90 questions and depending of your answer it will display a list of the first 3 options of what professions are more appropiate for you.

**The process:**

```
var vars = [ calc, cFis, CBio]; //array of variables with numeric values of test results.
var keys = object.keys(vars);
var newArray = [];
var names = ['Cálculo', 'Cientifico - Físico', ect]; //array of the names of the professional abilities

//first sorting the array
keys.sort(function(a,b) {
    return vars[b] - vars[a];
});
//create newArray whit the results
keys.forEach(function(key) {
    newArray.push(names[key] + ' : ' + vars[key]);
});
//print results
document.getElementById('primero').innerHTML = newArray[0];
document.getElementById('segundo').innerHTML = newArray[1];
document.getElementById('tercero').innerHTML = newArray[3];
```

**It will show:**

```
Cálculo : 60
Cientifico - Físico : 45
ect.
```

**The problem**

The `vars[key]` has to be approximated to a percentage using a table of pre-defined values, like this:

```
Cálculo test points are between  60 - 65 then % must be 80%
```

Now the string to print must be like : `Cálculo : 80%` now, asuming that I have 3 professions and 3 diferents % values, `Cálculo : 80%`, `C - Fisico : 60%`, `art : 30%` I have to display in order of their % value like:

```
Cálculo : 80% C - Físico : 60% Art : 30%
```

**Is there a way to get the numeric characters on a string for sorting the array in numeric order? like the example above?**

I was trying something called *natural sort* but it always sort the arrays using the alphabetic value before the numeric ones. like:

```
Art : 30% Cálculo : 80% C - Físico 60%
```

Comment: You don't need to use `Object.keys` on an array. In your `forEach` function, the second parameter can be the index. You could do `names.forEach(function(name, i) { newArray.push(name + ' : ' + vars[i]); });`

Comment: I don't get what `calc`, `cFis` and `CBio` actually contain. And please explain the logic behind `Cálculo test points are between  60 - 65 then % must be 80%` there's nothing in your code that corresponds to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is convert the strings into numbers (removing the `%` at the end), then sort the array in descending order:

```js
var arr = ["Art : 30%", "Cálculo : 80%", "C - Físico: 60%"];
arr.sort(function(a, b){
    // Substring between ": <substring here>%".
    a = +a.substring(a.indexOf(":")+1, a.length - 1);
    b = +b.substring(b.indexOf(":")+1, b.length - 1);
    return b - a; // decending order
});
console.log(arr);
```

For items such as `"Art : 30%"` you will want the start the substring at the index of `":"+1`.

---

Another way you can do this is to use regular expressions, matching the digits in the strings using `.match(/\d+/g)` to return the string that only contains digits.

```js
var arr = ["Art : 30%", "Cálculo : 80%", "C - Físico: 60%"];
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  a = +a.match(/\d+/g);
  b = +b.match(/\d+/g);
  return b - a;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Just be careful of using the second method, it won't work if there are numbers being used other than the ones as percents. For example if one was `"Art1 : 30%"` the second method would not work. One way to get around that is to use `/\d+%/g` and then remove the `%` at the end.